# Flask via uWSGI on Nginx and worker killed by signal 9

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

For some reason when my Flas app is deployed to the Docker it will crash on multiple requests with an error

```
nginx    | 2020/06/26 20:41:39 [error] 20#20: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "POST /api/v1.0/export HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://172.18.0.2:5555", host: "127.0.0.1:80"
flask    | DAMN ! worker 4 (pid: 16) died, killed by signal 9 :( trying respawn ...
flask    | Respawned uWSGI worker 4 (new pid: 18)
```

The app works fine when run on `venv`

uWSGI config looks like:

```
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file = run.py
callable = app
socket = :5555
processes = 16
threads = 2
master = true
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
harakiri-verbose = true
```

and nginx config looks like:

```
server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass flask:5555;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    client_header_timeout       120s;
    client_body_timeout         120s;
    keepalive_timeout           120s;
    send_timeout                120s;
}
```

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Have you ruled out memory? Try 1 process and 1 thread. If that works, you're likely running in to a resource limit. (I'm assuming your Flask app it configured to use port 5555 instead of the usual 5000.)

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar problem and did the following changes:

```
reload-on-rss=4048
threads=10
enable-threads=true
harakiri=130
```

For me this solved the issue.